# Find item between row and column in

Tags: javascript

So I want to find the index of a coordinate, according to the first array, like this:

1- values_to_find=['AA','CC','TC']
2- matrix to find the values_compare:

[image]

So, in order to find the value of the first element, of the values to find, I would get 12.
In the end I want another array with just the values, like this:
values_to_use=[12,25,34].

So far I have this code:

```
function cal_extinction_coefficient(str) {

    var values_compare= [['Values', 'A','C','T'], ['A', 12,14,16], ['C',23,25,26],  ['T',31,34,37]];
    
    var values_to_find=['AA','CC','TC']

    let chunk=0;
    var all_combLength= values_to_find.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < all_combLength; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < values_compare.length; j++) {
             const final= times[j].includes(all_combinations[i].slice(0,1));
             
        }

        
    }
```

However, I don't know how to access this values... I have the same resolution, but in pandas and with python...
Can someone help me please?

Comment: You don't want to start at `i = 0` since that's your row header. Ditto with `j = 0` as that's the column header. Then you have some other variables that are not defined, like `times` and `all_combinations` that don't appear to be needed. I would just translate the `values_to_find` to numerical coordinates. So `'AA' = [1, 1]`, `'CC' = [2, 2]`, `'TC' = [2, 3]`. Then just get the values there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to locate a row with `find` and then scroll to the column with `indexOf` on the column titles.

```js
var values_compare = [['Values', 'A', 'C', 'T'], ['A', 12, 14, 16], ['C', 23, 25, 26], ['T', 31, 34, 37]];

var values_to_find = ['AA', 'CC', 'TC']

var values = values_to_find.map(([r, c]) => 
    values_compare.find(row => row[0] === r)
        [values_compare[0].indexOf(c)])

console.log(values)
```

If the matrix is big and/or used many times, you might want to create an index for all row/column combinations.

Comment: Thank you for the help.This code really helped me!